# Trying to implement Swiper.js to tbody tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I need to make my `<tbody>` auto-swiped without affecting the content inside `<thead>`, but I have problem when implementing it. I cannot place `swiper-wrapper` class since the HTML does not allow `<div>` tag inside a table and the Swiper.js itself does not allow `swiper-wrapper` to be inlined with `swiper-slide` class because it will broke the layout.

Is there any solution to do so? Please take a look at my code.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-auto-swiped">
        <thead>
            <!-- there will be 5 <th> element inside this tag -->
        </thead>
        <tbody class="swiper-wrapper swiper-slide font-weight-bold">
            <!--
               there will be 10 rows of data to display for each swiper-slide class
               and it will be swiped using autoplay feature provided by Swiper.

               but it does not allow swiper-slide class to be inlined with the
               swiper-wrapper class, the layout will be messed up.
             -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<script>
  var autoSwipeTable = new Swiper.default('.table-auto-swiped', {
    //
  })
</script>
```